# The method cellLocationChanged is undefined for the type activity

Tags: android, telephony

I want to display the signal strength and cell id and lac. I ve created a listener for both SIGNAL_STRENGTHS and CELL_LOCATION. I still cant get the proper value when connected in UMTS (its stack showing -1) and I cant get to display the cell id and the lac. Ive added another method inside my listener class to listen for location changes. I dont know if its correct though. The onCellLocationChanged() method belongs to the PhoneStateListener so why Im I geting this? Thank in

```
package com.example.gsmdata;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.telephony.cdma.CdmaCellLocation;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;

public class GsmDataActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 


int network_type;
int signal_strength;
int cid;
int Lac;
int bts;

TextView network, signal, ci, lac;
TelephonyManager phone ;
GsmCellLocation CellId;
CdmaCellLocation baseStation;
SignalStrength phone_sig;
signalStateListener listenphone;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    


    network = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNetwork);
    signal =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSignalValue);
    ci = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCiValue);
    lac = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLacValue);

    /* Update Listener and start it */

    phone = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    listenphone= new signalStateListener();
    phone.listen(listenphone, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);

    network_type = phone.getNetworkType();

    switch (network_type){         
    case 1: network.setText("GPRS");break;
    case 3: network.setText("UMTS");break;
    case 4: network.setText("CDMA");break;
    case 8: network.setText("HSDPA");break;
    case 9: network.setText("HSUPA");break;
    case 10: network.setText("HSPA");break;
    case 13: network.setText("LTE");break;
    default: network.setText("UNKNOWN");break; 

    }


}
@Override
protected void onPause()
 {
   super.onPause();
   phone.listen(listenphone, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);


}
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
   phone.listen(listenphone, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS  |PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);

   network_type = phone.getNetworkType();

   switch (network_type){         
   case 1: network.setText("GPRS");break;
   case 3: network.setText("UMTS");break;
   case 4: network.setText("CDMA");break;
   case 8: network.setText("HSDPA");break;
   case 9: network.setText("HSUPA");break;
   case 10: network.setText("HSPA");break;
   case 13: network.setText("LTE");break;
   default: network.setText("UNKNOWN");break; 

   }


}

private class signalStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

    @Override

    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength phone_sig){
    super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(phone_sig);


    if (network_type==1){
        signal_strength = phone_sig.getGsmSignalStrength();
        signal.setText(-1*(113-(2*signal_strength)) + "dBm");

    }
    else if(network_type==0){
        signal.setText("Unknown Network type");
    }
    else{
        signal_strength= phone_sig.getCdmaDbm();
        signal.setText(signal_strength + "dBm");    
    }

    }
    }


    public void onCellLocationChanged(GsmCellLocation CellId){
        super.onCellLocationChanged(CellId);

        ci.setText(CellId.getCid());
        lac.setText(CellId.getLac());
        /*bts= baseStation.getBaseStationId(); 
        Lac=cellId.getLac();*/

    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what was missing from my code.

```
CellId=(GsmCellLocation) phone.getCellLocation();
```

if I add this line of code everything works and I can see the Cell Id and the LAC of the Base Station

Comment: its not working with Lte and UMTS type network why is that and what is the solution

Comment: @Ateeq http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCellInfoChanged(java.util.List<android.telephony.CellInfo>)